# opencart - Increase field size of address in table setting - config_address

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, opencart

how to increase field size of address in table setting --> config_address ?

Now i see in structure of config_address is Type : TEXT in phpMyadmin , so i need change from TEXT to LONG TEXT ?

Answer (score 0):

`LONGTEXT` can hold up to 2^32 bytes, as specified in the [mysql data type storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).